# How to determine in what order do I need create tables from an ERD

Tags: sql, database, create-table

After I have created the data dictionaries for each table, and drawn up an ERD. In what order should the tables be created?
Here is a picture of that ERD:

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to create constraints after all tables have been created.

Comment: Just a remark: I must admit, I always have difficulties to read such ERDs. Is this one correct? Each order can have many order lines which can contain many products each which can have many suppliers each. On the other hand suppliers can only offer one product each? Well, that seems wrong. But reading it the other way round seems wrong also. It seems strange that all relations are 1:n. Or am I misreading the diagram? As to the answer: I agree with the others :-)

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner that diagram doesn't look correct (though maybe I'm reading it incorrectly). Logically it seems like an "OrderLine" should only ever link to one product (i.e. it's a single item on the order), but the same product can obviously be ordered multiple times. Same for the Supplier - Product link. A product should generally be coming from a single supplier, whereas a supplier is likely going to be supplying more than one product.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. To me that just looks like an odd way of denoting a foreign key (i.e. many suppliers can offer the same product) but it's still wrong in the sense that if that's the case then really you'd want a ProductSupplier table otherwise you have multiple entries in product that are identical bar the SupplierId. I'd suggest you might want to consider your design a bit more carefully before committing to it as it stands.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I will refine it as necessary. I just mainly wanted to know how I would go about creating it once completed.

Comment: I don't see your question as too broad, so as to put it on hold. The question is clear; the answer is easy. Either create all tables first and add all foreign keys later, or start by creating all the tables that have no foreign keys, then iteratively add those with foreign keys only on the already created tables. If circular references exist you will have to create the associated tables first and add the foreign keys later. So first creating *all* tables and then adding the foreign keys later is definitely the easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

do all the table creates first, then do all the foreign key constraints AFTER all the tables are created.

OR

create the tables with constraints in the correct ORDER so that constraints don't fail.

SOURCE: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/how-are-foreign-keys-resolved-when-creating-tables-in-batch

Comment: "create the tables with constraints in the correct ORDER so that constraints don't fail." They're asking how they determine what the correct order is.